# Object initialization and looping inside 'for'?

Tags: c++, class, loops, constructor, operator-overloading

I have attended an interview today and the interviewer was asking me the following question to implement and fill-in the code inside a class.

```
class I
{
// code to be filled in
.....
.....
.....
};
int main()
{
for(I i=0; i<10; i++){ // to make this for loop work, what needs to be written in the class above?
cout << " " << endl;
}
......
......
return 0;
}
```

Its not clear to me, and I was unable to answer it. Can somebody let me know about the problem?

Comment: You have to implement these three operators used in the loop.

Comment: Your I must be comparable to the possible data types of 10

Comment: @MikeCAT You mean =, < and ++ operators? Oh the operator overloading.

Comment: I made a mistake. you will have to implement operators `<` and `++`, and constructor `I(int)`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Why post an answer in a comment?

Comment: @highlander141  Was this interview relative to a vacancy of a team lead?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Nah it was for Senior Software Engineer

Comment: @highlander141 Unfortunately I am not invited at interview even for a junior position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this statement

```
for(I i=0; i<10; i++){
```

it follows that the following constructions

```
I i=0;
i<10;
i++
```

shall be valid.

So the class needs a (non-explicit) constructor that can accept as an argument an object of type int. And the class shall have an accessible copy or move constructor.

There should be declared `operator <` either for objects of the class or when one operand can be of the type int.

And the class needs postfix increment operator `operator ++`.

Here is a demonstartive program. I added operator << for clarity.

```
#include <iostream>

class I
{
public:
    I( int i ) : i( i ) {}
    I( const I & ) = default;
    bool operator <( const I &rhs ) const
    {
        return i < rhs.i;
    }
    I operator ++( int )
    {
        I tmp( *this );
        ++i;
        return tmp;
    }
    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &, const I & );
private:
    int i;
};

std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const I &obj )
{
    return os << obj.i;
}

int main()
{
    for ( I i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

If you want that this loop would be valid

```
for ( I i = 10; i;  )
{
    std::cout << --i << ' ';
}
```

then the class definition can look like

```
#include <iostream>

class I
{
public:
    I( int i ) : i( i ) {}
    I( const I & ) = default;
    explicit operator bool() const
    {
        return i != 0;
    }
    I & operator --()
    {
        --i;
        return *this;
    }
    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &, const I & );
private:
    int i;
};

std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const I &obj )
{
    return os << obj.i;
}

int main()
{
    for ( I i = 10; i;  )
    {
        std::cout << --i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the required operators (`<` and `++`) and a matching constructor (`I(int)`):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class I
{
private:
    int index;

public:
    I(const int& i) : index(i) {}

    bool operator<(const int& i) {
        return index < i;
    }

    I operator++(int) {
        I result(index);
        ++index;
        return result;
    }
};

int main()
{
    for(I i=0; i<10; i++){ // to make this for loop work, what needs to be written in the class above?
        cout << "A" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```